# Is there a benefit to deactivating a MegaShield after an outpost has been cleared?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

So I've cleared some outposts and I'm wondering what the purpose of the megashield is after it's been cleared.

The narrator explains that megashields can be deactivated to attract blood dragons to help clear an outpost, but after the outpost has been cleared, is there any point?

Comment: I do not understand your question what are you trying to ask.

Comment: @Stizzle84 After an outpost has been cleared, why can you still turn the shields on and off? Should I leave them on or off?

Comment: Why would you want to turn them off?  If you were being chased by a Blood Dragon they will stop them entering the OP.  You have the ability to turn them in in order to aid you taking the outpost, I guess it just wasn't worth the coding to remove that functionality afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real reason to turn off the shields once you've cleared an outpost.  In most cases, nothing particularly interesting happens, and I can honestly say I never did it during my playthrough.

You can kite enemies into the base this way, and that might be useful for, say, fighting a Blood Dragon - there's a lot of offensive hardware and expendable NPCs in one of these bases.

That said, it's also very useful to be able to walk through the shield and keep yourself relatively safe from harm.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in doing so. While attacking an outpost, deactivating the shield will attract Blood Dragons that can help you by clearing most of the outpost by themselves. Of course, afterwards you'll have to take care of the Blood Dragon. They'll have taken damage in the process of clearing the output, so picking them off afterwards would be easier.

Once an outpost is cleared, there's no benefit in deactivating the Mega Shield.